# Zend_db_table: How to Select with a Mysql Keyword

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

Any Ideas how I can build the following query with the zend_db_table class?

```
SELECT SUM(x) FROM traffic
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't actually use `Zend_Db_Table` at all, but if you know how to configure basic queries, use this expression instead

```
$ZendDBTable->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(x)');
```

Read it as pseudocode, I don't know the syntax of `Zend_Db_Table`.
The `new Zend_Db_Expr('some mysql keywords')` is used to let the engine know that you have a keyword in the query which should not be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more descriptive code sample:

```
$table = new DbTable_Traffic(); //extends Zend_Db_Table
$select = $table->select()->columns('SUM(X)');
```

Expressions containing `()` will be transformed to `Zend_Db_Expr` automatically.